# Dynamically add elements to object

Tags: javascript

Here is the object I want to re-create dynamically

```
var myPath = {
    one: [
        new google.maps.LatLng(1,2), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(3,4))
    ]};
```

Here is my try without success:

```
var myPath2 = {};
var newFieldName = 'one';
myobj[newFieldName].push(new google.maps.LatLng(1,2));
myobj[newFieldName].push(new google.maps.LatLng(3,4));
```

I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Another try:

```
var myPath2 = {};
var newFieldName = 'one';
myobj[newFieldName].add(new google.maps.LatLng(1,2));
myobj[newFieldName].add(new google.maps.LatLng(3,4));
```

I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

how can I add/push a new element?

Comment: I think you mean `myPath[newFieldName].push(new google.maps.LatLng(1,2));` You named the object `myPath`, not `myobj`. `.push` is used for adding elements to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to set the field value to an array, then you can [push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) elements into it.

```
var myPath2 = {};
var newFieldName = 'one';

// Set field value to an array
myPath2[newFieldName] = [];

// Then you can push elements into it
myPath2[newFieldName].push(new google.maps.LatLng(1,2));
myPath2[newFieldName].push(new google.maps.LatLng(3,4));
```

Comment: @lucidgold Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
myobj[newFieldName] = []; // initialize the array
myobj[newFieldName].push(new google.maps.LatLng(1,2)); // push (not "add" as you used)
```